# How to use jQuery's trim() function

Tags: javascript, jquery, trim

As discussed in many questions on stack - IE 8 wont accept `.trim()`, but the jQuery framework takes care of that.

I don't know how to translate my function to use that version of trim (I thought I was already using jQuery), could someone advise? Here is my code:

```
$('input').val(function(index, val){
    return val.replace('Please Select', '').trim();
});
```

This is designed to replace the string with nothing.

I've tried:

```
$('input').val(function(index, val){
    return val.replace('Please Select', '')$.trim();
});
```

but that was no good.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

```
$.trim(val.replace('Please Select', ''))
```

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/

Comment: Thanks -knew it had to be something simple, thanks for the link to the doc. I'll accept when it lets me.

Answer (score 7):

IE8 doesn't have a native `trim` method, generally, I just augment the prototype:

```
if (!String.prototype.trim)
{
    String.prototype.trim = function()
    {
        return this.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,'');
    };
}
```

This is the shortest regex to trim a string, but I have heard it say that `.replace(/^\s\s*/,'').replace(/\s*\s$/,'')` is (marginally) faster... the choice is yours

If you really want to use jQuery for this, of course, you'll have to make the target string the context of the called method (`$.trim` calls the method on `$` === the jQuery object), so make the String a jQ object:

```
$('  foo bar  ').trim();//returns "foo bar"
//compared to augmented prototype:
'   foo bar  '.trim();//returns "foo bar"
```

The benefit of an augmented prototype is that you don't have the additional overhead of creating a new jQuery object, whereas using the prototype-approach relies on JS to wrap the string in a native String object and apply the method to that. Basically, it's the same operation, but it *should* be a marginally more efficient, because jQuery does a bunch of checks to any string passed to the jQuery constructor (`$()`)

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
$.trim(val.replace('Please Select', ''));
```

Here's the [Trim()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/) entry in the documentation.